# Trying to alter SKU field on ubercart product that is also a course

Tags: 7, ubercart, forms

I'm trying to modify a course (from the course module) and a product (from ubercart). I want to remove the SKU (right now I'm just testing how to remove the required bit) and a few other fields as I'm selling only online products. I'm not great at using hook_form_alter() yet.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial, http://www.ubercart.org/comment/8749/Re-Removing-SKU-product-edit-page and I'm not quite sure where he is getting `$form_id == 'product_node_form'` - is that related to the content type?

I'm trying to do this on a course content type, so if so, that would explain why it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID for a node form is built up in [`node_forms()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_forms/7):

```
$forms[$type . '_node_form']['callback'] = 'node_form';
```

Where `$type` is the name of each type retrieved from [`node_type_get_types()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_types/7).

So generally speaking, if the content type is `product`, the form ID will be `product_node_form`, if the type is `course` the form ID will be `course_node_form`, and so on.

Comment: Hrm, doesn't actually work for some reason, so I guess I will be using devel now.

Comment: Ah, my order of arguments was off.